# Temperature rising every day after replacing old thermal paste

Tags: cpu, gpu, hp-pavilion, thermal-paste, thermal-pads

I have high temperature issue with HP Pavilion G6 Series, 60 to 75 degree when in idle mode.

Removed old thermal paste (which was thick & hard after many years of usage) and replaced it with Arctic Mx-4, cleaned the laptop and vent with compressed air and followed all the suggestion on different forums and on SU, following is result;

First day idle temperature of TZ01 was 55 degree,

Second day idle temperature of TZ01 was 58 to 60 degree,

3rd day idle temperature of TZ01 was above 60 and today, the fourth day see the attachment

[image]

Where ambient temp was 30 to 32 degree

Questions

Why Core#0 and Core#1 temp have 10 degree difference?

GPU Temp seems Okey in idle mode like 50 degree?

Board Temp TZ01 is rising with every day usage (Note: I replaced Thermal Pad with Thermal Paste) Can this be the reason? if yes then what Thermal Pad I can use, I throw away the old thermal pad and don't have a clue about it's thickness.

This what happen when playing game

[image]

Board & Processor Temp goes upto 85 degree where GPU temp max 69 degree.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several problems:

1. Your system could be collecting dust quickly. If it is located on the floor, try to place it on a table. Keep animal-hairs out of it. etc.
2. You might have had a thermal-paste-accident. Check if the thermal-paste is, where it belongs and didn't get squeezed anywhere it doesn't belong (this is most likely your problem).
3. Are your cooler-fans working efficiently?

The difference between the two cores could have to do with thermal-paste being smeared where it doesn't belong on one side and not the other.
Could also be, that the programs you're using only use one core.

Your GPU-Temperature seems ok to me.

The board-temperature rising is also an indicator, that you might have thermal-paste on it on places, it doesn't belong.

Clean off the excess thermal-paste.

Comment: updated the question and also it's laptop (no body put laptop on floor) and it has one cooling system for both CPU & GPU so if GPU Temp is good then should be CPU too, will check the thermal paste, may be it will be reason but Mobo chip has only heatsink (which had thermal pad now replaced with thermal paste) no air cooler which is my main concern because with time it's idle temp is rising

Comment: Thermal pad usually has a higher heat conduction resistance so using paste has advantages. Do you notice that although the temperature is at 84 degrees the fan power only reaches 30%? At this temp they should run at 100% throughput. Check for obstruction or wrong software parameter (in BIOS or SpeedFan control sw).

Comment: @user1016274, BIOS setting is fine, Fan speed set on Auto, the 30% is some default setting in  Fanspeed Tool, in idle mode the Fan speed is around 700RPM where if you see the snapshot when core#1 Temp is 85 degree fan speed is above 1000RPM, I'm ordering the Arctic Thermal Pad, I think the reason the temp is spiking because Thermal paste can be effective with Copper Heatsink & aircooler but not with Silver Heatsink and the other reason which I think the CPU temp is rising because i applied too much thermal paste.

Comment: the question remains is what size of thermal pad, 0.5mm or 1mm thick?